# Using where clause or similar way with JSON

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to pass an input value using a post request and retrieving on another file with isset() set value and trying to get the outcome where the value is in in the JSON as below.

A.php - where I make the API calls and retrieve JSON

```
global $decoded_result;
$decoded_result = array();
$decoded_result = json_decode($result, true);
```

B.php - where the input is sent

```
    $("#_inputDropdown").change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var _zid = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-id');
         $.ajax({
            url:'c.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {_zid:_zid},
            success:function(data){
                $('#_eid').val(data[0].invoice_number);
                $('#_customerName').val(data[0].customer_name);
            }
        });
    });
```

C.php - when the input id is sent to C.php, that's where the JSON set for the particular input will be returned.

```
if(isset($_POST['_zid'])){
    $rows = array();
    global $decoded_result;
    global $result;
    $row = echo json_encode($decoded_result['invoices']);
    foreach($decoded_result['invoices'] as $result) {
        //HOW WOULD THE JSON WILL BE RETURNED WHERE THE id = _zid
    }
    $json = json_encode($rows);
    echo $json;
}
```

How should I approach since I am trying to retrieve from JSON nodes. finding a similar way as MySql.

Comment: Well in the simplest case, just write an `if` in your loop to check the ID, and only add the item to $rows if the ID matches your desired value. But rather than looping, you can google how to search inside arrays which contain associative arrays or objects, using PHP. There are lots of existing solutions. Because actually you're not searching in JSON, you're searching in a PHP array. Once you run json_decode, the data stops being JSON and just becomes an ordinary PHP array, so existing techniques for searching such arrays will work. The fact the data came from JSON is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for associative arrays in order to complete this task. as per it is

```
if(isset($_POST['_zid'])){
    $zid = $_POST['_zid'];
    global $decoded_result;
    global $result;
    $newArr = array_filter($decoded_result['invoices'], function($result){
        return $result['invoice_number'] == $_POST['_zid'];
    });
    $json = json_encode($newArr);
    echo $json;
}
```